# Can't add stock, custom attributes, and meta when creating product with php for magento

Tags: php, magento

I am making a script to help make it easier to import products into our magento installation and it now partially works. I am however having issues adding the stock quantaty and anything else that has to do with stock as well as meta title, description and keywords. I also can't add my custom attribute which is called EAN. Here is my code which I have commented to help understand what works and what does not work.

```
Mage::init();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$product->setSku($itemid);
$product->setName($name);
$product->setDescription($desc);
$product->setShortDescription($longname);
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->setTypeId($prodtype);
$product->setAttributeSetId($attributesetid); // need to look this up
$product->setCategoryIds($categorys); // need to look these up
$product->setWeight(10.0);
$product->setTaxClassId(2); // taxable goods
$product->setVisibility(4); // catalog, search
$product->setStatus(1); // enabled
//After this nothing is added
$product->setMetaTitle($name); //does not work
$product->setMetaDescription($longname); //does not work
$product->setMetaKeywords($keywords); //does not work
$product->setEan($ean); //custom variable, does not work
$product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')); //does not work

// assign product to the default website
$product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId())); //This works

$count = 0;
foreach ($listOfImages as $imagePath) {
    $mode = array();
    if ($count == 0) {
        $mode = array("thumbnail", "small_image", "image");
    }
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, $mode, false, false); //works!
    $count++;
}
//This does not work at all
$stockData = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$stockData->assignProduct($product);
$stockData['qty'] = $stock;
if ($stock > 0) {
$stockData->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
} else {
$stockData->setData('is_in_stock', 0);
}
$stockData->setData('manage_stock', 1);
$stockData->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 1);
$stockData->setData('stock_id', 1);
$stockData->setData('store_id', array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
$product->setStockData($stockData);

//Saving the product works
try {
    $product->save();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Handle the error
    print_r($ex);
 }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of searching I figured it out. Since I am in a file outside of Magento i needed to create the admin session aparently. This has solved most of the issues I had. I added the following code.

```
// Set an Admin Session
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(1);
$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setUser($userModel);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
```

Answer (score 3):

For Stock try

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$stockItem->assignProduct($product);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('qty', 1);

$product->setStockItem($stockItem);
```

See [Set default product values when adding new product in Magento 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289371/set-default-product-values-when-adding-new-product-in-magento-1-7)

For Keywords - `$product->setMetaKeyword()` (without the final 's') see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/193431/

Comment: Thanks, I got stock working by saving the $product and then declaring the stockitem and saving that as seen here http://blog.magentoconnect.us/creating-magento-products-on-the-fly/ I am still unable to get meta tags and the custom attribute to work though